# How to store string data type in shared memory?

Tags: c++, shared-memory, mmap

I want to create a program where one instance of the application will create the structure and put into a shared memory like `mmap` or `shm` and other instance will share the data.

One problem I am facing that is "How to write string data type into shared memory", as per my knowledge string class will allocate memory at the runtime and that will be in application address space.

I have following structure which i want to share with other process...

```
struct Node
{
   int id;
   string description;
   struct Node* child[10];
   //some other data types
};
```

I am able to share the data between the process if i am using structure like this

```
struct Node
{
   int id;
   char description[20];
   struct Node* child[10];
   //some other data types
};
```

but I don't want to use `char` array, can anybody suggest for any possible solution...

Comment: You can use Boost.IPC's shared memory allocators.

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB, I will check for the Boost library.

Comment: Not an answer since you stated that you don't want to use it, although I think that a char array would be a solution for you.  You do have to provide a maximum length, but you could make an interface to work with std::string as much as possible.

Comment: In theory it could be possible to provide an allocator for `std::string` that would use that shared memory somehow, but that would probably require a memory manager on that memory that would be synchronized between two instances.

Comment: Thank you @stefaanv and @Bartek, I will try to manage my code with `typedef basic_string<char,char_traits<charT>,some_allocator> string`

Answer (score 0):

For string, you can store like this:
One share memory stores fixed size members
    struct Node
    {
       int id;
       char* desc_address;
       int desc_size;
       struct Node* child_address;
       int child_size;
       //some other data types
    };

Another share memory stores dynamic size values:
So desc_address and child_address can point to another Shared_Memory.

Here use strategy: split dynamic and fixed.